# Функция записи в файл клиента

Tags: php

Мне нужно код, что б когда человек заходит на сайт, у него на компьюторе в файл `D://site.txt` записывался текст, к примеру, "Текст 1", если можно пример пожалуйста.

По ошибкам предыдущей темы. Мне не надо фтп, мне надо что б на компьютер записывалось.
Мне не надо на сервере хостинга, мне надо на компьютере клиента.

Answer (score 3):

Так сделать нельзя.

Comment: Почему? Нету функции записи данных на компьютер клиента, а как это можно организовать на сайте? С помощью какого языка?

Comment: Потому что я бы за такое нашел автора сайта и сделал ему биодефейс) Если научным языком, это небезопасно. Попросите человека скачать с вашего сайта экзешник, который создаст этот файл. Но его никто качать не будет =)

Comment: пользуйтесь стандартными функциями

writetoclientfile_with_blackjack_and_hookers($file);

Comment: я ведь ещё в заголовке вопроса написал, а можно пример ?

Comment: `*рукалицо.jpg*`

Comment: да, конечно.
$file = "C\WINDOWS\...\USER32.DLLЭж

writetoclientfile_with_blackjack_and_hookers($file, 'я твой комп винда ломать');

Answer (score 3):

Ты можешь только отдать на скачку такой файл. `header('Location: /site.txt');`

Answer (score 0):

Для чего хранить на компьютере клиента? Создайте у себя на хосте, Вы же как я понял делаете для себя, чтобы потом считывать информацию. А если даже для юзеров - создавайте для каждого юзера отдельный файл на хосте.

Answer (score 0):

Ну разве что можно хранить какие - либо значения в кукисах. )